# how to open openedge version 10 dictionary using openedge version 11?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I need to open openedge version 10 database using version 11 database dictionary.I m trying to open the database dictionary using version 11 but a message saying "use R10 data dict to open this R10 data dict". Can I open R10 database using R11 database dictionary?
I don't have any idea regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: atleast mention the reason for down voting....

Comment: The dictionary and admin tools are tied very closely to the specific database version. If you have v10, you should have access to the v10 tools. Perhaps if you tell us *what* you are trying to do we can help?

Comment: @lavinio actually I have a version 10 database dictionary shortcut in a shared folder which actualy exists on another machine. I could access the shortcut when my machine had ver 10. but now my machine has ver 11 and that shortcut is of version 10 dictionary( as db is on that machine with ver 10).hence not accessible now

Answer (score 1):

First, I would note there are things in the v11 Data Admin tool which won't work at all with a v10 DB since v10 db's don't have the same functionality of a v11 db.

Having written that, Progress platforms are designed to allow the clients to connect to databases one version ahead of the current client version via a client-server connection to support upgrading a database and then migrating the clients later.

I don't *think* it works the other way (a client can connect to a database one version back). What I'd suggest you try is connect to the db client server, and see if that helps.

If that doesn't work, then talk to your Tech Support resource, or check out the PSC KB: 
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/progresskbsearch#

Most likely, you're out of luck and will need to upgrade the db to version 11 in order to use the version 11 Data Admin tool.

Comment: You might want to test that.  Traditionally clients can connect to *older* databases.  IOW an OE10 client can connect to v9 or OE10.  A v9 client cannot connect to an OE10 database.  There has been talk of relaxing that but I don't know that it has gone anywhere -- I haven't tested it but, SFAIK, an OE10 client cannot connect to an OE11 db.